# String Formatting JAVA - Fixed Size with Variable Strings

Tags: java, string, format

-- First of all excuse me for asking such a question while other similar ones exist, however I haven't been able to solve my answer --

I am trying to output a list of hotel rooms of which I wish each output to be 20 characters long. I have used the following code:

```
String tempHotel = String.format("%-" + 20 + "." + 20 + "s", this.nameOfHotel) + "//"; //the "//" are used in this case to measure length
```

However my outputted strings are uneven in size. 
For instance I have outputs such as for instance:

```
Grande Bretagne     //
Hotel Maxim            //
Kepinski        //
```

Is anything wrong with my code? I have inspected multiple other answers

Comment: When using "hardcoded" String instead of `this.nameOfHotel`, everything is ok, length of each line is equal to each other, so it works well. Is there any possibility that code setting value of `nameOfHotel` variable add extra spaces after the name of hotel?

Comment: I am getting the data from an API so I fear that maybe the data I am parsing is faulted this way.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more of code you use in this example ?

Comment: You do know that `"%-" + 20 + "." + 20 + "s"` is the same as `"%-20.20s"`, except longer, right?

Comment: if I add a "." it adds it correctly such as in "Grande Bretagne." yet leaves a once again abnormal amount of spaces later